# Why does my hosts.deny not work on OSX 10.8?

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, mac-osx-server, hosts-file, denyhosts

For testing it I added these four lines to my `/etc/hosts.deny` file:

```
# /etc/hosts.deny
ssh-agent:ALL
sshd:ALL
```

I waited some time and then I tried to gain ssh access to the loop-back IP address. But I still get this:

```
$ ssh root@localhost
Password: ▊
```

And I can access it. I even tried it with adding entries explicitly denying access from 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tcpwrappers (which uses the entries in hosts.deny) has been removed from OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion), so sshd is no longer paying attention to what is in that file. You can use Packet Filter instead, or install libwrap via MacPorts and recompile sshd.

Run "**man pfctl**" to get details on how to control and configure the rules.

There's a nice run-down on how to use **pfctl** here:
[A Cheat Sheet For Using pf in OS X Lion and Up](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/a-cheat-sheet-for-using-pf-in-os-x-lion-and-up/)